# Javascript error: Object #<HTMLFormElement> has no method 'getElementById'

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm getting a Javascript error: Object # has no method 'getElementById'. I'm trying to have a button that transfers a selected element to another select box in HTML. Have looked everywhere but nobodies solution seems to work for me =\

Javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
function addDivision()
{
    var selected = document.frmSubmit.getElementById("selectedDivisions");

    var div = document.frmSubmit.getElementById("divisions");
    var divId = div.options[div.selectedIndex].value;
    var divText = div.options[div.selectedIndex].text;

    var newOption = document.frmSubmit.createElement(divId);
    newOption.text = divText;

    selected.add(newOption,null);
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="content">
<form id="frmSubmit" name="frmSubmit" action="">


<div id="Step1Content">
    <h2 style="float:left">Step 1:</h2><p style="float:left; padding-top:10px; padding-left:20px;">Select your divisions</p>
    <div style="clear:both">
        <select id= "divisions" name="divisions" size="8">
    <?  //Getting divisions based on League_id
        $getDivisionsSQL = "Select * FROM level WHERE League_ID = '1' AND disabled = '0'";
        $getDivisionsQuery = $db->Query($getDivisionsSQL);
        while( $divRow = $db->GetRow($getDivisionsQuery) )
        {
            echo "<option id=".$divRow['id'].">".$divRow['description']."</option>";
        }
    ?>
        </select>
    <?  
        echo "<img id='doAdd' width='40px' height='25px' style='position: relative; bottom:75px; cursor:pointer;' src='".$baseImagesPath."greenArrow.png'/>";
        echo "<img id='doAdd' width='40px' height='25px' cursor:pointer; style='position: relative; bottom: 25px; right:40px; cursor:pointer;' src='".$baseImagesPath."redArrow.png'/>";
    ?>  
        <select style="position:relative; right:40px;" name="selectedDivisions" id="selectedDivisions" size="8">
    <?  //List of divisions to use

    ?>  <option>Apple</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</div>





<div style="padding-top:50px; padding-left:50px; width:100%; float:left; ">
    <h2 style="float:left">Step 2:</h2><p style="float:left; padding-top:10px; padding-left:20px;">Select the starting date of games</p>
</div>

<div style="padding-top:50px; padding-left:50px; width:100%; float:left">
    <h2 style="float:left">Step 3:</h2><p style="float:left; padding-top:10px; padding-left:20px;">Select the total number of weeks in the season</p>

<div style="padding-top:50px; width:100%; float:left">
    <input type="submit" value="Create Schedule">
</div>
</div>

</form>
</div>
```

Comment: IDS are singular, you CANNOT have more than one element with the same id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is happening because you're trying to use `getElementById` from a node element, and this method belongs to `document`. It's logical when you think about it: **IDs are supposed to be unique** inside your page, so there is no point in using a dom element in order to "filter" an element by id.

So, if you change from:

```
document.frmSubmit.getElementById("selectedDivisions");
```

to:

```
document.getElementById("selectedDivisions");
```

everything should work as expected.

---

As a sidenote, `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementsByClassName` are supported for node elements - they are used to select all the child nodes which match the name of the tag/class specified.

Check API reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! now i'm getting an error: Cannot read property 'value' is undefined. I know that i'm giving each entry a value and this is the error that made me but frmSubmit there in the first place.

Comment: As I said, you can't use `getElementById` from an element (it will not work), so you should use `document.getElementById` instead of `document.<element>.getElementById` (that includes `var div` either).

Answer (score 1):

A form object is of type `HTMLFormElement`. As already noted you can invoke `getElementById` on a `document` but not on an `element`, including not on an `HTMLFormElement`.

But a form contains elements and it is reasonable that given an HTML form element object one would want to access specific elements within that form element, so how to do that?

Well, your `HTMLFormElement` provides a property named [`elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements). Accessing the `elements` on your `HTMLFormElement` yields a [`HTMLFormControlsCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) which contains the elements found within your form. `HTMLFormControlsCollection` is derived from the type [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). There is one read-only property for an `HTMLFormControlsCollection` and two methods.

The property is `length` which returns the count of elements found within the collection (which in this case would be elements in your form element).

The two methods are:

- `item(index)` - which returns the specific node at the specified zero-based index. Returns `null` if `index` is out of range.
- `namedItem(id)` - Returns the specific node whose ID or, as a fallback, name matches the string specified by id. Matching by name is only done as a last resort, only in HTML, and only if the referenced element supports the `name` attribute. Returns null if no node exists by the given id/name.

So thge solution if one has a form object of type `HTMLFormElement` is to access the object's `elements` property, invoke `namedItem( id )` on it using the `id` of the element you want to retrieve from your `HTMLFormElement`.

The syntax is:

```
let element_obj = form_obj.elements.namedItem( id )
```

Where `form_obj` is your `HTMLFormElement` and `id` is the id of the element in the form that you want to access.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a function which belongs to a `DOMDocument`, not a `DOMElement` ([*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)).

`document.getElemendById()`

The valid version of your code is actualy:

`document.getElementById("selectedDivisions");`

**Note:** ID attribute should be **unique**, which means if two or more elements have the same ID in your document, the page is considered [**invalid** by W3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id).

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use jQuery for this. You can just grab the the element you want from one select and append it to the other.

```
    $('#selectedDivisions').append($('#divisions'));
```